# How to make a Xaml element available to all classes?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button with an `X:Name` of `Email`

```
<Entry Placeholder="Email" x:Name="email"Keyboard="Email"x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```

I want to access the entered data from a separate class

```
public class separateClass: ContentPage{
     string x = email.Text;
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

I keep getting errors telling me that

> email does not exist in the current context.

Comment: you need a reference to the instance of the page containing email in order to do this.

Comment: Seems like you are new on OO, I'm right? `email` exists only at the parent class context (for example 'MyContentPage.email') and to access it, as @Jason said, you should refers to an instance of this class (for example `var test = new MyContentPage();` then `test.email.Text = "new text";`). Beside this all, Whatever your are trying to do, it is conceptually wrong.